# How to show keyboard when starting a dialog?

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, keyboard

I want to show keyboard when i open my dialog.

This is my code:

```
var array: Array<String> = arrayOf("Edit", "Delete")
 val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activityContext)
 builder.setTitle("Options:").setItems(array, DialogInterface.OnClickListener {dialog, which ->
        if(which == 0) { //edit
           val mDialogView = LayoutInflater.from(activityContext).inflate(R.layout.activity_contact_info_description_dialog, null)
           val mBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(activityContext).setView(mDialogView).setTitle("File name")
           val mAlertDialog = mBuilder.show()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

AlertDialog dialog = builder1.create();
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: I don't understand what is this...i have no dialog variable. Read my code i have mDialogView mBuilder mAlertDialog

Comment: You are using AlertDialog from different import

Comment: Yes i want to use alertDialog

Comment: Many [example](http://45.76.113.195/?questions/2115758/how-do-i-display-an-alert-dialog-on-android?answertab=oldest)